# How to make assets in SASS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, assets

In Rails, when we include an image into the page we use `image_tag` helper, which generates `<img>` tag and adds `?nnnnn` at the end of its url, so that every time an image is updated the old version would not be stuck in the cache on the client side. Same thing for SASS needed, but I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using helpers provided by sass-rails gem https://github.com/rails/sass-rails, (scroll to Asset Helpers).
These helpers can be used from inside sass files any time you need to reference an asset (image/audio/video/font)

body{
  background: asset_path($relative-asset-path, $asset-class);
}

Note: image_url("...") is not working on Rails 3.1.0.rc4 due to a bug, but you can still use asset_url and asset_path.

Answer (score 0):

Using `stylesheet_link_tag` will do this for you, just the same as `image_tag` does. This also applies to JavaScript files linked in with `javascript_include_tag`.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I need it for things like `background: url('/images/logo.png');` inside a SASS file.